# Elasticsearch NEST - document immediately after indexing is not found

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using .NET NEST for searching in Elasticsearch.

When I index a document and immediately search for it it is not found:

```
var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
settings.DefaultIndex("products_test");
settings.DisableDirectStreaming(true);
ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);

Product p = new Product("My Product", "6");
client.IndexDocument(p);

var results = client.Search<Product>(s => s.Query(q => q.MatchAll()));

results.HitsMetadata.Total //is 0 and results.Hits are empty
```

Why?

Do I have to commit somehow?

Thanks

EDIT: But when I run the Console App again and comment out the creation, the document IS found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An indexed document is not *searchable* until the document is [written to a shard segment of an index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html). The [`refresh_interval` index setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings) is responsible for how often this occurs, with a default of 1 second. Note that an indexed document is immediately available after indexing, retrievable by ID.

When indexing a document, you can specify that a refresh happens following indexing, so that the document is searchable after the response is returned

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

client.Index(new MyDocument(1) { Message = "foo" }, i => i
    .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
);
```

or calling the Refresh API

```
client.Refresh("my-index");
```

In a production environment however, it's generally not recommended to do this because writing many small segments will have a larger performance impact on the cluster with regards to resources and segment merging operations. It can be useful for ad-hoc and testing purposes however.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Yes, my problem occured when writing tests, so your solution is perfect fit for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wait for index refresh after document indexing:

```cs
await client.IndexAsync(document, x => x.Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor));
```

Just ask Elasticsearch to refresh index at any time:

```cs
await client.Indices.RefreshAsync("your_index_name");
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html